# How to dynamically change a var in the application using k8 config maps?

Tags: java, kubernetes, cron

I have a requirement of changing a var in the application on the fly. currently, we add a cron job for the path in the file system of the pod to which K8s adds a specific variable to.

Unfortunately, cron jobs are not working for more than one vars. we are using incron for tracking file directory to which these vars are added. Any suggestions on alternative and better ways to do this?

Comment: Can you post the YAML manifest of your K8s jobs? Not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Please define what you exactly mean by "dynamically" and "on the fly". Do you want to change a variable value in a running Pod ? Without restarting it ? You can [define environment variables from configmap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data). Does it meet your requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate use case for ConfigMaps. ConfigMaps are static and only applied to a Pod during its creation process. Changes to a ConfigMap require the Pods that use it to be recycled. There is no native solution for lifecycle management of data stored in ConfigMaps.

For dynamic configurations, a custom operator is needed. Otherwise, Redis or Consul might be a better fit.